# Get a parameter value from an url with TypeForm

Tags: typeform

I need my survey to accept redirect url links that we’ll send panelist to based on their status: Completes, Overquota, or Terminate.

Additionally, my survey has to collect panelist ID that will be passed in the url and send it back to the firm during the redirect so that the film can credit panelists who complete my survey and update statuses for terms and overquotas.

How can I make it in TypeForm please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can do this by using a combination of Hidden Fields and a dynamic redirection URL.

Start here to learn how to use Hidden Fields to receive a value as part of the Typeform URL: https://www.typeform.com/help/hidden-fields/

Then use this article to see how to use information gathered in the Typeform itself (or contained in the hidden fields) to create a dynamic redirection URL: https://www.typeform.com/help/pass-information-from-one-typeform-to-another/

Good luck!

Comment: Hello Alejandro, thanks for your docs. It help me understanding.